# Use CSS3 transforms to center viewport around mouse click position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I would appreciate your help with the following issue: I want to use CSS3 transforms in order to center the view-port of the browser around the position of a mouse click.
Please have a look at my commented example at http://jsfiddle.net/XjpdU/.

The problem that I have is that the translation works fine only on the first click. After the first click the distance between the center of the view-port and the mouse click position seems to be computed correctly, but the translation seems to jump just anywhere.

I have tried to explicitly set 'transform-origin' (-webkit-translate-origin in my example) to the position of the last click (i.e., the current center of the view-port) but it seems that with 'translate' the 'transform-origin' directive simply gets ignored.

Thanks for helping out!y

Answer (score 0):

Yep, transform-origin has no effect on the translation. It works like this:

> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X, Y and Z values of ‘transform-origin’
> 3. Multiply by each of the transform functions in ‘transform’ property in turn
> 4. Translate by the negated computed X, Y and Z values of ‘transform-origin’

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering

What you could do is remember the translate, and add the newly calculated one to it, this will cause a relative translation starting from the previous point.

```
x = prevX = prevX + newX
y = prevY = prevY + newY
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XjpdU/1/

Comment: You're welcome :) Please note that it's recommended to mark answers that solved the problem in question as accepted (the little checkmark next to it), it's not only about reputation, but also helps others to pick the right information (assuming there are more answers), it's an indicator for other questioners and respondents that the question is solved, and others will be more encouraged to answer your questions when they see that it won't be for nothing.